# Customize error validation on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can add the error message into `@errors` on controller then show it on the view like:

`<%= @question.errors[:tag][0] %>`

with tag is not model element.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this part of the Rails validation guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators).  They work by creating a custom validator, which just appends the desired error message to the desired hash entry.

In your case, this might look like:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with :tag_validator
end

class TagValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(question)
    unless question.special?
      question.errors[:tag] << 'Not special enough.'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with error messages in rails is done in 3 steps viz.

1. Validating the active record object using [rails-validation-helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers) OR creating a custom validator as specified by @chaleyc
2. Validating the ActiveRecord(AR) object using AR [validation methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html)
3. Showing the errors on views, creating a view helper is the best practice [notices and errors on rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529136/notices-and-errors-on-rails3)

Here's a nice [rails-cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3) to get you started